# Python extract element from iterator

Tags: python, iterator, multiprocessing

I have the following code but cannot get out the results from the iterator

```
from multiprocess import freeze_support
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()

    pool = ProcessPool(nodes=4)
    results = pool.uimap(pow, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
    print("...")
    print(list(results))
```

The code does not error it just hangs.

Comment: [Your original code runs just fine when I try it.](https://repl.it/repls/ExhaustedFunnyCharacterencoding)

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple subtleties to get this to work, but the short version is imap or uimap are iterators unlike map in the python multiprocessing example. To extract the results it needs to be in a for loop. If inside a class you also need the called method to be a @staticmethod

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f(vars):
    return vars[0]**vars[1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()

    pool = Pool(4)

    for run in pool.imap(f, [(1,5), (2,8), (3,9)]):
        print(run)
```

Comment: The code here didn't work because of the `for` loop; it worked because your `f` takes a list of arguments instead of two separate arguments.

Comment: This above code does work, pool.map or pool.imap are iterators and so need the for loop per the requirements of the iterator.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work; I'm saying the reason it works has nothing to do with the `for` loop. `list` would have been perfectly fine. Both `for` loops and `list` will iterate over an iterator.

Comment: Also, you switched from `pathos` to regular `multiprocessing` and from multiple iterables to a single iterable of tuples.

Comment: [Here's a demo of `list` working fine.](https://ideone.com/O6ordp)

Comment: Actually, [here's a demo of your original code working fine too](https://repl.it/repls/ExhaustedFunnyCharacterencoding) - apparently the confusing `uimap` docs were actually trying to say it does work like the built-in `map`.

Comment: That's amazing thanks! On windows it seems,  if you run that with pathos.multiprocessing the list(pool.imap...) causes it to hang but list(pool.imap) does work with Python's multiprocessing . Then it works in the Repl.it with no changes! All good to know. Thanks again...there was a lot going on in that little chunk of code.